# How do you calculate the pressure for a precise amount of steam from a certain volume of water?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

This may be a fairly stupid question, but I will ask it anyway.

I am currently trying to calculate the steam pressures required to hold one litre of water using steam in a $500\mathrm{ml}$ container. The steam will be condensed back into water when extracted from the containment chamber. I am not sure of the exact ways to calculate this as nothing comes up online when calculating steam pressures from water.

I know water expands $1600$ times when in the form of steam, but I am not sure at what pressure that would be at when held in a container.

I am also not sure whether this question applies to the physics StackExchange, but I think it is probably the most appropriate StackExchange category.

So, what PSI pressure would the steam be at when held in a $500\mathrm{ml}$ container with a water volume of $1\mathrm{L}$?

Comment: At what temperature?

Comment: If there's both water and vapor present at equilibrium (i.e. it's a mixed phase), then the pressure is just the vapor pressure at whatever temperature. Incidentally, the chemistry stackexchange covers physical chemistry.

Comment: {Clarification} The temperature is 30 degrees celcius

Comment: 30 degreees WHAT?

Comment: Dude, 1L of water in a 1/2L container? The pressure required will be a bit high.

Comment: I understand the pressure will be very high but I have the infrastructure to handle that.